# Appcelerator - The screen appears small on Iphone x

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I tested my app on Iphone X, and the screen appears small ( two black spaces on the top and bottom) as shown on this [image], how can I fix this bug ?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to select required full screen in targets , general, deployment info...

Comment: @iOS thats for native, tot in Titanium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't add a splash screen for the iPhone X resolution, which is required for it to work full screen on an iPhone X.

Furthermore, you'll need to use TiSDK 6.3 or higher.

You can see the files you'll need here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-src-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-iOSgraphicassetrequirementsandoptions

But I'd recommend using a storyboard as a launchscreen instead, that'll resize everything for you and it will be more flexible in the future too. You can see that here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Launch_Files

2020 edit: As of iOS April 2020 launchsreen storyboard is now mandatory by Apple. Splash screens are no longer an option